# Will this sentence make any sense to readers? Grammar question

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

We sat on the ground in the alley i remember, talking about anything.
OR?
I remember we sat on the ground in the alley talking about anything.

Is the first one grammatically correct?

Comment: As it stands, the first says it is the alley which you remember; with a comma after *alley* it would have the same sense as the second, that you remember sitting on the ground talking; but with commas bracketing *in the alley* it would be the location, which you remember, the fact that you were in the alley at the time.

Comment: I don't know if the rules of grammar would rule it out as wrong, but the first statement is certainly *unclear*.

Comment: As with all English sentences, it depends entirely on how you say it. Out loud. There are two possible intonations for the sentence that convey quite different meanings and would never be ambiguous in speech.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the blanket "Is it grammatical?" question it asks amounts to a request for editor vetting/proofreading of the sentence. At the very least, the poster should explain what in the sentence(s) seems dubious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want these sentences to be equivalent.  In that case, put a comma after" alley" in the first version.  This makes "I remember" an aside applying to the whole sentence.  This avoids having your reader think you're calling to mind the alley only, as in "the alley that I remember."

Put a comma after "alley" in the second version as well, to set off the gerund "talking."  (And remember to capitalize the personal pronoun "I" wherever it occurs in your sentences.)

"Anything" sounds a little odd to my ear.  Better to use "everything" to indicate a completely open, wide-ranging conversation.  Or modify "anything"  -- "talking about anything that came to mind" or "talking about anything that might remind us of Paris."

Both versions are grammatical, and which you use should depend on what you want to emphasize, the event in the alley or your remembrance of it.

Comment: If you mean you were talking about any kind of different subjects, you can say 'talking about anything and everything'. This would be better than just 'anything', which does sound odd.